# Is the diode in this circuit connected in parallel with the resistor?

Tags: voltage, circuit-analysis, resistors, diodes, voltage-clipping

Using the example below my teacher started to explain the parallel clipping circuit.

[image]

Then he said that the diode is connected in parallel with the resistor but I couldn't understand why, because I think they are connected in series.

Could you tell me where I'm wrong?

Comment: Diode is indeed connected in series with resistor. But the output voltage is taken across diode and E1 voltage source. So, if you connect a load resistor across the output terminal the situation will change. But try it yourself.

Comment: All circuits are voltage dividers. With a series (input) element and a shunt (output) element. Here the series is the resistor; the output is formed of the diode and the biasing-for-the-diode which sets the clipping level.

Comment: If he is teaching this, he should have explained it.  Just at a glance it is obvious that it is in series with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually it is both, in truth parallel and series is dependant on your viewpoint.

What appears to be in series form one viewpoint may appear in parallel from another.

Looking at your circuit that \$+ V_O -\$ makes all the difference.

If you redraw your circuit like this perhaps you can understand.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2flW07m.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The terminals Vo+ and Vo- now have two circuits attached to them. One circuit is a signal source with an output impedance. The other circuit is a 10V clipper circuit. So you can legitimately say the circuits are connected in parallel across the terminals.

**Point of view makes all the difference.**

Consider the following two resistors.

[image]

Obviously in series right? What about now?

[image]

Did you say still in series? Actually the correct answer is **both**!. It depends on where you look from. Looking from the left or right they are in series, but looking from the join between the resistors, they are in parallel.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

What we say isn't always precisely what we mean.

I think he meant to say 'the diode is connected in parallel with the signal at Vout'.

In this case, the signal Vin is generated by the AC source, and goes through a resistance R, before being read at the + and - terminals of Vout.

The diode/battery combination is in parallel to the signal at Vout.

There is an alternative clipping circuit, a series clipper, where the diode would be in series with the R, being placed in the line between R and Vout+.

Having said that it's a parallel clipper, it's 'obvious' to your teacher and any engineer that the diode is in parallel to Vout, and in parallel to where the resistor R connects to Vout. This is probably the source of his momentary lapse in precision. Of course, it's not obvious to somebody learning.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's in parallel with \$R\$ as far as the load at \$V_o\$ and the AC circuit are concerned.

**DC analysis:**

The -10 V DC source biases the diode, having the effect of "moving" its forward voltage 10 V down so that \$V^{\prime}_f = V_f -10\$. When the sine input is superimposed to the DC bias, the diode will behave as a non-linear resistor \$R_D\$ according to its V-I curve. Note than the diode will clip when the sine voltage across the diode goes below  \$V^{\prime}_f\$, and that we can also embed this behavior in the non-linear characteristic of \$R_D\$.

**AC analysis:**

Thus we end up simply with a voltage division between \$R\$ and \$R_D\$. If we calculate the equivalent Thevenin resistance of the AC circuit, we find it to be \$R_{th} = R || R_D\$, which is indeed **a parallel of \$R\$ and the diode**, and which will be highly non-linear as well. Now you can load the output of the circuit with any load you want and calculate the output voltage with precision.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fDQ2Mfm.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>